# How do I add dynamic attributes to a django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working with a django form that looks like this:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    image.widget.attrs["onchange"]="this.form.submit();"
    stream_id = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    stream_id.widget.attrs["style"]="display:none;"
```

For the stream_id field, I would like to prefill the value based on the corresponding field of a related model I have in my database. How do I modify my template code to add an attribute that will let me prefill it?

I would like to avoid using JS if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you using `ModelForm` or not populating it in the `__init__` method for some reason? Why should it be on _template_?

Comment: I did not know I could use the init option, I'm exploring that atm. ModelForms didn't seem feasible because the form only modifies one field in an otherwise larger model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically modify your form by using **init** and self.fields dict. Something like this:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, something=None, *args, **kwargs):

        super(UploadImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['stream_id'] = something
```

Comment: I'm trying this atm, but it looks like the autopopulated field is returning the "This Field is required" error. Do you know why that would be?